# Best machine learning technique to classify signals into either 1 of N categories or none at all?

Tags: machine-learning

I'd like to use machine learning to determine s a signal is 'good' or not.  Currently I think my approach should be to train a classifier to first recognize that signals exist in N categories (with N unknown), and then determine if any new traffic fits into either one of the N categories or none.  I know I could do some form of unsupervised learning to determine the N categories if I have a good set of known 'valid' signals.  I know I then could use a Bayes classifier to determine if any new signals are in one of the N sets, but I'm unsure if a Bayes classifier could also tell me that any 'bad' signal cannot be classified into any one of the N set.  Furthermore, I'm not sure if my approach is the best one to use.

Comment: Without any domain information (what are these signals? what kinds of categories?), don't expect a whole lot of help.  Well, I wouldn't expect much.

Comment: I do not think there is a 'best machine learning' technique as it is known that it suffers from the 'no free lunch theorem'. Unfortunately, you will have to test several methods and assess which one fits better your domain.

Comment: @vicsana - thanks.  Though will a Bayes classifier be able to tell me if a new signal does NOT belong in one of the existing N sets?

Comment: As far as I know, Bayes works on a set of hypotheses. I guess you could always have N known signals and then add a new category which represents unknown signals. You could train this new category with samples that you know that do not belong to any of the N known categories. However, I am not sure about the performance that you may get with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a generative model such as an RBM. That can take a input datapoint and tell you how probable it is given the training dataset it has seen thus far (assuming you train it only on good signals). Alternatively, compute the average similarity to the 'good inputs'. Those that are dissimilar would be likely to be noisy. Or compute the standard deviation over each field, and use that to inform you how much and new example deviates from the norm. What you are describing is likely an anomaly detection problem. Although as @vicsana states there is no free lunch, doing some research on this area will likely point you in the right direction.